# If the only subspaces invariant under $T$ are $\mathbb R^n$ and the zero subspace, then $U$ is diagonalieable.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let  $A$  be an  $n  \times n$ matrix  with  real entries.  Let  $T$  be  the  linear  operator  on $R^n$ which  is represented  by  $A$  in  the  standard  ordered  basis,  and  let  $U$  be  the  linear operator  on  $\mathbb C^n$ which  is represented  by  $A$  in  the  standard  ordered  basis. Show that, if  the  only  subspaces invariant  under 
$T$  are  $\mathbb R^n$  and  the  zero subspace,  then  $U$  is diagonalizable.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint 1:** every real $n\times n$ matrix has an invariant subspace of dimension $1$ or $2$.

So $n\leq 2$.
The only non-trivial case is $n=2$.

**Hint 2:** since the degree $2$ characteristic polynomial of $T$, which is also the characteristic polynomial of $U$, has no real root (otherwise there would be a real eigenvalue and aone-dimensional invariant subspace), then it has two distinct conjugate complex roots. Hence...

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** We know that an $n\times n$ matrix is diagonalizable if and only if the sum of the dimensions of its eigenspaces is $n$.

Suppose that isn't the case.  Can you find a proper, nontrivial subspace which is invariant under $A$ in this case?